# Strange behaviour with floated elements which appear to have relative positioning

Tags: html, css

I am going through a book on responsive web design in which the author builds the webpage at this address: http://responsivewebdesign.com/robot/

Since the webpage is responsive, if you view it at a browser screen width greater than 1025px, you can see that the h1 element with class logo sits on top of the unordered list with classes nav and nav-bar (the ul being the navigation bar).

See the below link to the screenshot taken of the webpage in Chrome Developer Tools for an example of what I mean by this.

ul with nav and nav-primary classes highlighted in Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]

As you can see in the above image, that unordered list which composes the navigation menu bar sits underneath the h1 logo element. You can go to the website, open it in your browser and see this for yourself.

Now with the background information given here's my question.

How is it that h1 element with logo class is able to sit on top of ul with nav and nav-primary classes?

As far as my understanding goes, you would normally have to have the unordered list with position set to absolute in order to do this (both are floated left), but upon inspection in Chrome Developer Tools both of the above mentioned elements have position set to relative.

I can not replicate this in the way that the creator has created it. What am I missing or not understanding here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the html and css I discovered that the h1 element with class logo is floated to the left in the css and the div element with class nav-bar alongside it did not have a float on it and hence had 100% of the width of the containing element and was therefore able to overlap the area taken up by the h1 element with class logo.

Answer (score 0):

The logo element in particular is positioned relative in order to be given a z-index, if the logo is given a z-index higher than that of the navbar then it would seem to be layered on top of it.

Comment: I am aware of the z-index which is allowing the logo to appear on top. That's not the part I'm struggling with. What I don't get is how when it appears that both the logo (h1 element with class logo) and the nav bar (ul with classes .nav and .nav-primary) appear to have relative positioning that there can even exist any overlap (ie - the nav bar should end up floated left alongside of the logo since both have relative positioning).